# how to unit test subprocess.call() to check is it called in python

Tags: python, unit-testing

Hey I am trying to write unittest to check if `subprocess.call()` called in the function flash_it that does not return anything.

```py
def flash_it('flash.bat'):
    file = open('file.txt', 'w')
    subprocess.call(['flash.bat', '-d'], stdout = file, stderr = subprocess.STDOUT)
```

```py
@mock.patch('subprocess.call')
def test_subprocess_call_passed(self, mock_subproc_call):
    main.flash_it('flash.bat')
    self.assertTrue(mock_subproc_call.called)
```

Comment: Please fix formatting of code in your question. Second thing is flash_it should probably have argument name in (), not a string

Comment: Is your function definition actually like this? why is there a `'flash.bat'` in the function definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably need something like this:

```
import subprocess
import mock


def flash_it(filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        subprocess.call(['cmd to flash', '-d'], stdout=f, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

@mock.patch('subprocess.call')
def test_subprocess_call_passed(mock_subproc_call):
    flash_it('flash.bat')
    mock_subproc_call.assert_called_once()
```

Note that I didn't actually run that.

Of course there is also `assert_called_once_with` that lets you assert what parameters were passed to function. Check documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html

EDIT:
Ok I've run it with pytest:
[image]

Comment: I have tried this approach already and went through the library. My approach works for  `self.assertTrue(mock_open.called)` open but not in this case. Sorry for formatting -- first question in stackoverflow.

Comment: `self.assertTrue(mock_open.called)` I'm quite sure that it'll always pass even if you don't invoke your function. `called` here is probably MagickMock, or Method object, both will always evaluate to True - so you are not checking for anything really

Comment: no just make sure that subprocess.call is called in the function.

Comment: Solved                                                                                                  
 `subprocess.call = mock.create_autospec(subprocess.call, return_value ='subprocess.call() flash with -d')
        main.flash_it('flash.bat')
        result = subprocess.call(['cmd', '-d'], stdout='file', stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
        print(result)`

Comment: Ok, you were right - your assertTrue worked. On the other hand I can't see how code from my answer doesn't work for you? It worked perfectly fine for me at least with pytest (see updated post)

Comment: Also in comment above you are just printing thing you've set up in mock, and that is not how you want your tests to work

Comment: The only test working in unittest for me ```python subprocess_call = mock.create_autospec(subprocess.call, return_value ='subprocess.call flash with -c mocked') ```